# How to handle large number of configuration parameters across a program conceptually?

Tags: parameters, configuration, configuration-files

Imagine a software system where you have like 100 parameters, each of which is sensible to change (in my case this is a reasearch system for machine learning). The obvious solution is to store all parameters in a config file, so that the system is easy to handle and see through.

Whis approach is better:

- a) load the config file at the entry point of the program and pass down a big collection of config variables through each method in the code
- b) load the config file at the entry point of the program and pass down the relevant collection of config variables through each method in the code
- c) load the config variables directly where they are needed
- d) load the config and make it global

I'm open for suggestions or examples of a particular implementation. At the moment I'm experimenting with nested config variables, each nested object storing config of different modules in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you do the following steps.

First, use a configuration file syntax that supports the concept of multiple sections/scopes, and preferably nestable scopes. For example, an XML element is a nestable scope in the sense I am talking about, while a ".ini" file provides non-nestable sections. A Java properties file does not provide direct support for scopes, but you can emulate such support by using the syntax `x.y.z` to denote variable `z`, in scope `y`, which in turn is nested in scope `x`. [Config4*](http://www.config4star.org/) (which I developed) provides direct support for nested scopes.

Second, write the constructor of a configurable `Foo` class as shown in the following pseudocode:

```
Foo(Configuration cfg, String scope) {
    _x = cfg.lookup(scope + ".x");
    _y = cfg.lookup(scope + ".y");
    _z = cfg.lookup(scope + ".z");
    _bar = new Bar(cfg, scope + ".bar");
}
```

In the above pseudo code, I use the `_` prefix to denote an instance variable, and I assume the `Configuration` class has a `lookup()` operation that takes a scoped name, for example, `cfg.lookup("foo.bar.abc")` will return the value of the `abc` variable in the `foo.bar` scope.

Third, the `main()` function of your application can be written as shown in the following pseudocode:

```
main(...) {
    String configFileName = ...; // obtain from command-line argument
    String scope          = ...; // obtain from command-line argument
    Configuration cfg     = parseConfigurationFile(configFileName);
    Foo foo               = new Foo(cfg, scope + ".foo");
    ... // create other configured objects
    doRealWork(foo, ...);
}
```

Finally, command-line arguments to your application should specify: (1) the name of a configuration file, and (2) a top-level scope (within the configuration file) that holds configuration variables for running the application. For example, let's assume `example.cfg` is structured as follows:

```
instance1 {
    foo {
        x = "a value";
        y = "another value";
        z = "yet another value";
        bar {
           ...
        }
    }
    ... # configuration for other objects
}

instance2 {
    foo {
        x = "...";
        y = "...";
        z = "...";
        bar {
           ...
        }
    }
    ... # configuration for other objects
}
```

You might run your application as `myApp.exe -cfg example.cfg -scope instance1`.

The above advice provides the following benefits:

- Your application can create multiple `Foo` objects, each of which can be configured differently, simply by passing a different `scope` parameter to the constructor of each object.
- Users have the flexibility of being able to store multiple sets of configuration variables inside a single configuration file, if they want. For example, a user might have different sets of configuration variables for: (1) different unit tests; (2) development, UAT and production environments; (3) multiple instances of a replicated server application.
- Over time, you can write a library of configurable classes that follow the above design principle. That library of configurable classes can be reused across multiple applications.

I have used the above approach in several C++ and Java Config4*-based applications that I wrote, and it has worked well for me. If you are using a language that has built-in support for reflection (such as Java), then an alternative approach is to use a dependency injection framework. If you don't know what that is, then do an Internet search for "dependency injection", "inversion of control" or "Spring Framework".

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer! The idea of multiple top level scopes is neat, I'll adopt this in my setup (Python, btw.).